# User scheduled email reminders in node.js and mongodb application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, scheduled-tasks

I have a node.js application hosted on aws that utilizes a mongodb database on MongoDB Atlas. I would like to add functionality for users to schedules email reminders as they wish. What would be best approach for this? I was considering a separate node application that continually monitors a database table containing the scheduling data/records, so not to slow down the main functionality of the application. Has anyone else manage to set this up successfully in a scalable way?

Comment: i have done this once, you will need to setup some of services to handle the stuff. but the main thing that you need is [AWS event bus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-bus.html) or `EvenBridge`

Comment: Thank you. And what sort of service did you use to continually search/check the database to see if it needed to do something?

Comment: AWS eventBridged will handle it using cron, so will need to ask the user to setup when the cron jon would be running.  `eventsBridgeAWS` has paramater `ScheduleExpression` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

Comment: Ok, thank you and understood.  So I would create an event that would retrieve a list of email reminders from mongodb then a function in aws (something like lambda) would process that and send the emails?

Comment: yeah, i was created some lambda function using microservice architecture, the user able to create their own function to be converted to lambda function. i cant explain all of them here, to long for sure.